# Flutter part of text is missing on mobile

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter web app. When I use it on my computer everything works fine. But if I use it on my phones browser parts of the Text are just missing. The Bounds of the text or the box dont matter, its just missing. Only if I press it, it shows the whole text. Has anyone an idea why that could be? Oh and when I shorten the text its the same. The last part is missing.
[image: Without pressing the button][image: with pressing it] [image: before pressing the button (this text is shorter than the one in the picture after this but it still isnt showing everything wtf??)] [image: after pressing it] [image: before] [image: after]

Already tried using FittedBox for the text but doesnt work. Thanks

**Code for the alertBoxes:**

```
void showCustomDialog(BuildContext context, String message) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: AlertDialog(
            title: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              child: Text(
                message,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Abbrechen",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
            ]));
  }
```

**First part of the dialog:**

```
Widget dialog(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Kategorie Hinzufügen?"),
      content: TextFormField(
        controller: textEditingController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Namen eingeben",
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.category_outlined)),
        onChanged: (String val) {},
      ),
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Text(
            "Abbrechen",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Apparently it happens when I use DuckDuckGo. When I use Chrome everything is fine. But when you use DuckDuckGo the last character of the String or if you have spaces everything behind the last space gets cutted. Hm strange

Answer (score 0):

The flutter team just fixed it on the master channel (1.26.0-2.0.pre.403). I have tested it and it works fine. Probably soon it will be on the beta channel.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65099

Comment: If possible, please provide a link as a reference.